# Finding limit $\int_1^L \frac{\sin(x)}{x^p}\,dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

My previous on finding integration of $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x^p}\,dx$ was closed and I was directed to [Prove that $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x^p}\, dx$ converges for $0<p<2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2064025/prove-that-int-0-infty-frac-sin-xxp-dx-converges-for-0p2)  this link.

I had one doubt in that soltuion and since the post was too old I though of creating new question.

There to show convergence of $\int_0^L\frac{\sin(x)}{x^p}\,dx$ it says

$$\int_1^L \frac{\sin(x)}{x^p}\,dx=\left.\left(-\frac{\cos(x)}{x^p}\right)\right|_{1}^{L}-p\int_1^L \frac{\cos(x)}{x^{p+1}}\,dx.$$

Now since both terms of on left converges for $p>0$ our integral also converges.

My doubt is why can't we directly use the inequality that $|\sin(x)|/x^p<1/x^p$ and claim since
$\int_1^L \frac{1}{x^p}\,dx$ converges for $p>1$, $\int_1^L \frac{\sin(x)}{x^p}\,dx$ also converges?

Comment: You could, but for $p>1$ only.

Comment: This is when we know p>0 is the answer. What if we are required to find the values of $p$. Then how would we know $p>1$ is not the complete answer?

Comment: You can do for example some numerical tests that suggest $p>0$ and then try proving it. This is how research often works.

Comment: For that route, Dirichlet's test provides better intuition since $\sin x$ is oscillatory.